# Javascript loop and insert new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, while-loop

I with ajax get this data:

```
[{"id":125,"price":225,"start":"Tue, 26 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":124,"price":200,"start":"Wed, 27 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":121,"price":67,"start":"Sat, 23 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":114,"price":45,"start":"Sun, 08 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":9},{"id":113,"price":55,"start":"Sun, 24 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":111,"price":55,"start":"Wed, 01 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"id":110,"price":53,"start":"Fri, 03 Jun 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":107,"price":53,"start":"Wed, 03 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":106,"price":55,"start":"Mon, 01 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":105,"price":53,"start":"Tue, 16 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8},{"id":104,"price":55,"start":"Thu, 21 Apr 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":11},{"id":101,"price":57,"start":"Wed, 17 Aug 2016 00:00:00 +0000","user_id":8}]
```

so as you can see there is `start` data.
I also have:

```
var start = '04/17/2016 12:00 am';
var end = '09/20/2016 12:01 am';
```

Now I need to make loop day by day from `start` to `end`, check if day(date) excist into json and if not add new data into json :

```
{"id":0,"price":100,"start":"DATE","user_id":0}
```

What is the best way to do that?

**UPDATE:**
I create one new with dates from start to end but now I need to put json into new array: http://jsbin.com/qekijumobe/edit?js,output

Comment: Probably with some kind of loop.

Comment: hm, yes but problem here becouse I have date ... how to make loop with date ?

Comment: well... dates have specific intervals. Seconds, minutes, hours, days, etc. what interval do you wish to loop on? then just count the number of intervals between start and end and loop.

Comment: just days, so loop need to go day by day ...

Comment: maybe I can use: moment().dayOfYear(); so this will return me number ...

Comment: Get the timestamp of both dates at a specific time of day, say, 1:00 AM, subtract smaller from larger, then convert the resulting value from milliseconds to days.

Comment: but why, I just can use simply: moment(start).dayOfYear(); - that give me number of day in year...

Comment: Hey, if that'l give you an accurate count, go for it. I don't use moment much so i can't say whether or not it will.

Comment: how to convert milliseconds to days ?

Comment: 1000 ms per second, 60 seconds per minute, 60 minutes per hour, 24 hours per day.

Comment: yes, / 86400000 ... and thats ok, but what next ...

Comment: well, that's how many days you need to loop through and ensure are covered in the array of objects.

Comment: yes I make this loop: for (i = start; i < end; i++) { 
    console.log('day'+i);
} but how to check is some 'i' day into json ?

Comment: there are several ways, ranging from looping over the array on each iteration looking for mathcing values, to pre-sorting the array and checking current index on each iteration and inserting a day into that position if it doesn't match the expected day.

Comment: what is the best and the most fastest way, can you show me example please

Answer (score 0):

My another answer had a fault in there, this is what I came up after it:

First, create a foreach loop, wich loops trough all of the  objects inside the array

```
for (var obj of objArray) {} //Use "of" instead of "in" tk get the values and not the indices
```

Then, inside this loop, check every field of the objects, if they're the same, abd if they're, then break out the loop, else, if there's no matching object, push it in the array.

```
function isInArray(yourObj) {
    for (var obj of objArray) {
        if (obj.id == yourObj.id && obj.start == yourObj.start && obj.price == yourObj.price && obj.user_id == yourObj.user_id)
             return true;
     }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: hm, no, I find new solution but now I just need to put one into other , please help: http://jsbin.com/qekijumobe/edit?js,output